# gitignore: Difference between *.o and /**.o

Tags: git, gitignore

gitignore: What is the difference if any between `*.o` and `/**.o`?

`*.o`: According to the documentation, this will match this file extension in all repository

`/**.o`: This is globbing with the same meaning

Answer (score 0):

With `/**.b` the double asterisks fall into the last category in the list below (from .gitignore's [help](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore#_pattern_format)):

> Two consecutive asterisks ("`**`") in patterns matched against full pathname may have special meaning:
>
> - A leading "`**`" followed by a slash means match in all directories. For example, "`**/foo`" matches file or directory "`foo`" anywhere, the same as pattern "`foo`". "`**/foo/bar`" matches file or directory "`bar`" anywhere that is directly under directory "`foo`".
> - A trailing "/`**`" matches everything inside. For example, "`abc/**`" matches all files inside directory "`abc`", relative to the location of the `.gitignore` file, with infinite depth.
> - A slash followed by two consecutive asterisks then a slash matches zero or more directories. For example, "`a/**/b`" matches "`a/b`", "`a/x/b`", "`a/x/y/b`" and so on.
> - Other consecutive asterisks are considered regular asterisks and will match according to the previous rules.

The previous rules say:

> An asterisk "`*`" matches anything except a slash.

I don't think /**.b will match anything<s>, because you cannot have files with '/' in the name.</s>

Comment: The `/` in `/**.o` is the leading slash that indicates the pattern is anchored to the directory containing the `.gitignore` directive. So it will match, e.g., `xyz.o` but not `sub/xyz.o`. You are correct that the `**` falls into the "regular asterisk" rule here, though.

Comment: @torek In git 2.17 `/**.o` does NOT seem to ignore `xx.o`, or `xyz.o`. `/xyz.o` ignores `xyz.o`. `/*.o` ignores both `xx.o` and `xyz.o`.

Comment: That's probably a bug, and might get fixed. I suspect it's not considered a high-importance bug though, since you should list `/*.o` or `*.o` anyway. :-) (The other option is to change the documentation to not say that `**` means the same as `*` here.)